# How to convert Script hash into opcodes, in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a script and it looks like this: `76a914af7a4a30243f2301e6a14a4979ae099d52f560d488ac`. How can I create an instance of class `Bitcoin::Script` from [ruby-bitcoin](https://github.com/lian/bitcoin-ruby/issues/291)? It has to be parsed, I believe, but how? I posted a GitHub [ticket](https://github.com/lian/bitcoin-ruby/issues/291) too.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I found an answer:

```
script = Bitcoin::Script.new([hash].pack('H*'))
```